# How to read pcapng (wireshark) files in Python?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a capture of some TCP packets in pcapng format and I'd like to open it in python to inspect the TCP payloads with address 192.168.1.198. I've only found this library: https://python-pcapng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/blocks.html but it does not support inspecting TCP payloads.

Is there an easy way?

Comment: [`pyshark`](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark)?

Comment: [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.utils.html)? Apart from that: you ask about reading pcapng. You don't ask about reading pcapng and also do more (somehow inspect TCP payloads) - yet you complain that the one you've found does not support this additional requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `python-pcapng` package. First install python-pcapng package by following command.

```
pip install python-pcapng
```

Then use following sample code.

```
from pcapng import FileScanner

with open(r'C:\Users\zahangir\Downloads\MDS19 Wireshark Log 08072021.pcapng', 'rb') as fp:
    scanner = FileScanner(fp)
    for block in scanner:
        print(block)
        print(block._raw) #byte type raw data
```

Above code worked for me.

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/python-pcapng/

Comment: This does not work for me. 

    `$ pip install pcapng`
    `Requirement already satisfied: pcapng in /home/bryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.25)`
    `$ python ./ReadWireSharkPoC.py`
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ReadWireSharkPoC.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pcapng import FileScanner
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileScanner' from 'pcapng' (/home/bryan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pcapng/__init__.py)
`

Comment: notice the package name is python-pcapng so `pip install python-pcapng`

Comment: how do I get packet tuples from these blocks?